# Microsoft Excel Copy paste without quotes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Problem 1:**

How to copy paste `cell` values from `Excel` file without copying the `quotes`(" & ")?

**Problem 2:**

Next line chars are also ignored while pasting

***Excel File Text:***

[image: Excel Text]

***Text after Paste:***

[image: Pasted Text]

**PS:** The only way I can do it without quotes is, by first pasting value in MS Word and then paste it in text file from MS Word file.

Comment: If cell contains newline, then excel copies cell value, enclosed in quotes (plain text part of copy buffer). I have not found any good solution; currently I'm building strings, using some uncommon character (#) instead of newline and replace # with newlines in notepad++. Of course it would be possible to create excel macro, doing all the same semi-automatically.

Comment: @Arvo Yes you are right.. if I remove the new line char then it get pasted as expected, but I need the new line char . do you have any work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's nothing much you can do about it. However there is a work around for it.

You can use `CLEAN` function as `=CLEAN(A1)` (specify your cell address). Then copy the text to notepad and you'll get the desired result.

But `CLEAN` function also erases line breaks from text as this function removes all nonprintable characters from text.

**EDIT1**:
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

[image]

This is the difference in result after copying.

[image]

**EDIT2**:
**__________________________________________________________________________________**

Here is a `VBA` solution. Try the following code:

```
Sub CopyToNotepad()
    Dim objData As New DataObject  'set reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim i As Long, FN As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim cell As Variant

    FilePath = "C:\test file\"   '---> give your file path
    FileName = "test.txt"        '---> give your file name
    FileName = FilePath & FileName
    FN = FreeFile

    Open FileName For Output As #FN

    Set MyRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A5")
    For Each cell In MyRange.Cells
        strTemp = Replace(cell.Value, Chr(10), vbCrLf)
        objData.SetText (strTemp)
        Print #FN, strTemp
    Next

    Close #FN
End Sub
```

To use the `DataObject` in your code, you must set a reference to the **Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library**.

This will give you output like below image:
[image]

Comment: how can i use clean function? can you give example?

Comment: @KyloRen - If your text is in say `Cell A1` then just enter `=CLEAN(A1)` in any cell say `Cell B1`.

Comment: But that removes the new line chars also, I want them in the pasted text

Comment: @KyloRen - Exactly, that's what I mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: but after applying clean function it's clearly visible that they have been removed  in cell B(n)

Comment: @KyloRen - Yeah unfortunately that's what `CLEAN` function do. But after pasting the data to notepad you can delete the column.

Comment: @KyloRen -  See the image in my answer. Result after using `CLEAN` function does give you the desired output.

Comment: the parenthesis are on the same line that's what i was pointing to, in my question that is problem two that i was addressing

Comment: @KyloRen - Okay, I thought you wanted it the way it is in your image in the question but without quotes.

Comment: @KyloRen - You can get your desired output either by going through `WORD` as you mentioned or using VBA by writing a `macro`.

Comment: @KyloRen - Are you okay with VBA solution?

Comment: I've looked into that solution... but if it's not very time consuming task..then I can go for that...

Comment: can you give me that solution?